# Laravel collection - get max value as float/int

Tags: laravel

There was a problem. Previously, the `share_price` column was a `float`, after which we had to change it to a `string`, because the client requested the use of not only floats, but also words.

To display the minimum and maximum values in the filter, use the `min` and `max` function.
But since appeared string, max value is now always string.
How to convert column to float in `max` wrapper?

```
$companyList = $companyList->get();
$maxValue = $companyList->max('share_price');
```

### UPDATE

It seems you misunderstood me a bit. This does not mean the conversion of the already obtained value, but when selecting the max value.

Example:

- 1.52
- 2.43
- 3.35
- STRING

When i get `->max()` - i get STRING, but need to get 3.35

Comment: what can `STRING` be ?

Comment: @ths any word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a collection, I'd suggest using filter to filter out all non-numeric items.

```
$companyList->get()
    ->filter(fn ($value, $key) => is_numeric($value->share_price))
    ->max('share_price');
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues::max`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.html#method_max) method accepts only one argument that can be either:

- a `string` that acts as the key to check in the collection
- or a `callable` (a function) that you may use to *filter* out `string`s in your case.

In your case, you can use a callback function that removes the `string`s, or precisely, treats the `string`s as `null`.

```php
/** we will simply tell the "max" method to treat strings as "null" */
$maxValue = $companyList->get()->max(fn($value) => is_string($value) ? null:$value);
```

The above code will:

- return the maximum number if at least **1** integer/float is found in the collection.
- return `null` if the collection is empty or contains **only** strings.

> The code sample above **DOES NOT** convert `string`s to their float/integer representation and even if you have a valid, castable `string` in your collection (like `"100"`) it will be treated as `null`.

Comment: I'd check for is_numeric instead since they appear to save all values as a string, regardless of their initial type. Great explanation though!

Comment: @Dan *"Find whether the type of a variable is string..."* [Source: `is_string` on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php). From that you can tell the this function checks the **type** of the variable just like the `===` operator checks the type. Anyway, it's a choice and I chose `is_string` because the OP provided a data sample that has *actual* numbers and *actual* strings.

Comment: @Dan Also, `is_numeric` returns `true` if it encounters a valid and castable string which the OP doesn't want based on his/her explanation: *"This does not mean the conversion of the already obtained value"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `floatval` function of PHP.

```
floatval($string);
```

or you can also cast your string value into float like below:

```
(float)$string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast $maxValue as int or float

```
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;
```

or the hacky way

```
$maxValue = $companyList->max('share_price') + 0;
```

Comment: max doesn't make sense for a string, You'll need to get a list of just the numbers and use max.